# Как правильно подключить android смартфон к opensuse (MTP)?

Tags: android, linux, opensuse

При подключении смартфона через USB кабель система видит мой смартфон, однако при попытке открыть в Dolphin его файловую систему, выдается ошибка. Google не выдал ничего вразумительного, лишь одну устаревшую, по всей видимости, информацию, и всякий мусор.

Comment: А пакет `gvfs-backends` в репах сюси есть?

Comment: 'gvfs-backends' уже установлен.
Нет кандидатов на обновление "gvfs-backends-1.28.3-2.2.x86_64". Самая последняя версия уже установлена.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно отладка по adb в настройках смартфона выключена и ее необходимо включить в настройках для разработчиков.

Comment: Она уже была включена

Comment: @U.S.DepartmentofState если у Вас прошивка CyanogenMod , то вам на 4pda.ru.ru/forum в тему Вашего устройства,  в настройках андроида выберите "тип подключения usb" и там выберите MTP, если уже выбрано, то все равно выберите еще раз. Попробуйте перепрошить на другую прошивку.